# How to prevent LCK_M_IX waiting/locking on the following Delete and Insert queries

Tags: sql-server, locking

*Edit: Solution turned out to be nothing in the answers here, I was using SQLAlchemy in Python, which is an ORM. I was executing the delete statement below in a transaction, but never committing it. This lead to around 10 open transactions occuring that eventually all needed to be rolled back, thus locking the entire table until rollback was complete.

Given the following table structure, records are being continuously inserted with the update_time of a very recent datetime. A separate Connection to the DB is periodically trimming old records with dates of older than 2 weeks.

Table Structure:

[image: Table Structure]

The following Insert is being run very frequently, with different values:

[image: Insert Statement]

The following delete statement is repeated until required, running a select right after to see if the process is complete

```
delete top(5000) from trade_options with (READPAST) where update_time < '<Two Weeks Ago>'
```

Activity Monitor shows that the Delete is locking, and the Insert is waiting ( LCK_M_IX):

[image: Image of the Activity Monitor]

Thanks

**Edit: Here are the Indexes/Keys as script outputs

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_order_option] ON [dbo].[order_option]
(
    [update_time] DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[order_option] ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [exchange_id] ASC,
    [symbol] ASC,
    [update_time] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: I have been debugging this, and it is only these two queries running. I have isolated the database, and I am also surprised that it's locking the whole table. Something is wrong here. I wonder if the delete statement needs an order by clause to prevent the scope reaching the whole table?

Comment: I have added the script output of both the Index (On update_time) and the keyed fields which also appeared under indexes in object explorer, however I'm not sure if that means that there is indexing on the keyed fields or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem has a name of `lock escalation`. You can read more on this here: [How to resolve blocking problems that are caused by lock escalation in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323630/how-to-resolve-blocking-problems-that-are-caused-by-lock-escalation-in).

> By default, SQL Server will acquire the finest-grain lock possible, in
>   order to attain the  greatest concurrency. In most cases, this means
>   SQL Server will acquire row (RID or  KEY) locks. SQL Server can
>   acquire hundreds or thousands of individual locks on data  in a single
>   table without causing any problems. In some cases, however, if SQL
>   Server  determines that a query will access a range of rows within a
>   clustered index, it may instead acquire page locks. After all, if
>   every row on a page is going to be accessed, it's  easier to manage a
>   single page lock than dozens, or hundreds, of row locks. In other
>   cases,  primarily when there is no usable index to help process a
>   query, SQL Server may lock an  entire table right at the beginning of
>   processing a query.

In your case I suspect there are some `indexes` on the table (this means that `delete` acquires locks on them too) or you do your deletes in one `transaction` (this means that all the `locks` are held until the end of the `transaction`). In this case this happens:

> SQL Server  will escalate locks **when any individual session acquires
>   more than 5,000 locks in a  single statement**. In this case, there is
>   no randomness in choosing which session will get  its locks escalated;
>   it is the session that acquired the locks.

So you should get rid of the wrapping `transaction` if it exists, or decrease `batch size` to a smaller one, or disable `lock escatation` on this table:

```
alter table order_option
set ( lock_escalation = disable )
```

> Do you think lowering the delete batch to less than 5000, or removing
>   the index would help? In the case of removing the index, wouldn't that
>   slow the delete considerably?

You should not drop this `index`, it helps you with your `delete`.

You can try batches of `2000 rows`, it should help.

I don't know the kind of queries that run against this `table` but it could make sense to have `clustered index` on `update_time` and `PK` as `nonclustered`

Comment: Thank you. The insert is wrapped in a transaction, but the delete is not. How might you interpret that? The insert happens withing an orm. Everything happens inside transactions and I can't prohibit that unfortunately.

Comment: You insert one row at a time and it's not insert to hold X lock on the whole table. It's your delete. But it gets more than 5000 locks at a time so I think you have indexes on yor table. Why don't you check for them?

Comment: Yes, there is an index on update_time, I have added that to my post above. Sorry, I was on my phone when I responded to you last time, so I couldn't check at that time. Do you think lowering the delete batch to less than 5000, or removing the index would help? In the case of removing the index, wouldn't that slow the delete considerably?

Comment: I updated my answer, decreasing batch size should help

Comment: I've accepted this answer, as I think not only did you provide a working solution (like others probably did), your explanation contains the best information. Thanks. I would like to know more about the recommendation around changing to clustered index, and PK nonclustered, but you answered the original question, so happy to accept.

Answer (score 2):

I see the above situation as very normal case when you want to delete and insert records at the very same time, not sure if insertion takes place only in working hour or even after working hour. I would suggest to put these delete statement inside a SQL job and schedule them everyday late in the night when there is very less/no activity on database. This would prevent any blocking on database.

As mentioned by Darko in previous answer, consider smaller chunks of data while performing delete and keep committing them upon completion. It would be even easier if you could create a view on top of this table and delete from there using your condition as explained by Mr. Brent Ozar [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/04/how-to-delete-just-some-rows-from-a-really-big-table/).

In case, you have operations running 24*7 then, its explained nicely with examples by Mr. Daniel [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3566/deleting-historical-data-from-a-large-highly-concurrent-sql-server-database-table/).

Hope above helps.

Comment: Yes in this case, it's 24/7 so the after hours approach doesn't work. I suppose I'm trying to make sure I have not missed something important here, as I'm not clear why there is contention here. In other words, why there is a wait occuring when the queries hit update_time values that don't conflict. Your link is very helpful, I will try the view approach.

Comment: Could you please include DDL of the table and query execution plan for delete statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should use smaller chunks when you deleting rows. But that would not solve your problem. If you execute the DELETE statement inside transaction the row lock might escalate to the table lock.

I don't know is it possible to apply table lock during the INSERT?  It means to use 'WITH (XLOCK)’ option.
Is that allowed by your apps?

What's more, it is not a bad idea to check indexes. Do you have one on ‘update_time’ column?

The moral of the story is that locking is normal SQL Server behavior and you can't avoid it. 
The only thing you can do is to reduce the waiting time.

There is a resource on the internet [Building a Custom Blocked Process Report](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/building-custom-blocked-process-report/) that might help you in order to be able to detect locking easily.